# Matplotlib live updating bar chart from CSV

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

New to python so any guidance would be appreciated!
I have a CSV that has names. I'm trying to count everybody with the name "Adam" and plot it in a bar chart. When the CSV gets updated I want the bar chart to update as well. Below is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import csv
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
myCount = 0
otherCount = 0
def animate(i):
    with open('test2.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['fName'] == 'Adam':
                myCount +=1
            else:
                otherCount = +=1    
    x = ["Adam","Not Adam"]
    y = [myCount, otherCount]
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.bar(x,y)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)            
plt.show()
```

Right now it shows me the outline of the graph but doesn't display anything.
Also, I got the animate function from another source. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Ok So I've updated the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import csv
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    myCount = 0
    otherCount = 0
    with open('testcsv.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['fName'] == 'Adam':
                myCount +=1
            else:
                otherCount +=1    
    x = ["Adam","Not Adam"]
    y = [myCount, otherCount]
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.bar(x,y)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)            
plt.show()
```

I know through testing that it's correctly grabbing the CSV and reading the data, but it's still not plotting it. The data looks like this:

```
fname,lname
Adam,Smith
Adam,Sandler
Adam,Smith
Adam,Sandler
Bruce,Willis
Adam,Smith
James,Harden
Bruce,Wayne
```

Comment: sample of data ?

Comment: Concerning "new to stackoverflow", you might want to read [mcve]. Concerning "new to python", you might want to look into the `pandas` library.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be three main problems with the code. The first two have to do with the counters in use. The last with the naming of the data.

1. `otherCount = +=1` is not valid python.
2. Incrementing a variable locally, does not change it globally. It would hence make sense to define `myCount = 0; otherCount = 0` *inside*  the animating function, in case you do not want to show cumulative counts.
3. The data column seems to be named `fname`, but the indexing uses `row['fName']`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I've updated the code. If you see anything else, please feel free to mention it.

Comment: Yup. It was that simple. I feel a little embarrassed. Thanks again!